# Cross compiling a Webots controller

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, cross-compiling, webots

I'm trying to use MinGW to cross compile from Linux to Windows a robotic controller (.exe) for Webots ([simulation software](https://www.cyberbotics.com/download)).

Webots supplies a [`Makefile.include`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20449179/Makefile.include) file common to all platforms, that prepares the building environment for compilation (necessary dependencies):

My current makefile, where I set several variables according to MinGW and my webots installation:

```
WEBOTS_HOME = /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home
#WEBOTS_HOME = /usr/share/webots

RESOURCES_PATH = $(WEBOTS_HOME)/resources/projects/robots/darwin-op
SOURCES_PATH = src
SOCKET_PATH = ../../../extra/socket/src

KIN_INCLUDE = ../../lib/OPKinematics/include
KIN_LIB = ../../lib/OPKinematics/lib/libOPKinematics64.a
EXT_INCLUDE = ../../lib/include

CFLAGS = -g -Wall
INCLUDE=-I$(RESOURCES_PATH)/libraries/darwin/darwin/Framework/include -I$(RESOURCES_PATH)/include -I$(KIN_INCLUDE) -I$(EXT_INCLUDE) -I$(SOCKET_PATH) 

LIBRARIES = -Wl,-Bstatic -lws2_32 -lpthread -lboost_system-mt -lboost_serialization-mt -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic $(RESOURCES_PATH)/libraries/darwin/darwin.dll $(KIN_LIB) 

CXX_SOURCES = $(SOURCES_PATH)/main.cpp $(SOURCES_PATH)/DarwinRobot.cpp $(SOURCES_PATH)/dyn_system.cpp $(SOURCES_PATH)/writefilestuff.cpp $(SOCKET_PATH)/socket_boost.cpp

#CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
EXE_EXTENSION=.exe
OSTYPE=windows
CFLAGS += -DWIN_MAKE

# ----------------------------------------------------
# 
### Do not modify: this includes Webots global Makefile.include
space :=
space +=
WEBOTS_HOME_PATH=$(subst $(space),\ ,$(strip $(subst \,/,$(WEBOTS_HOME))))
include $(WEBOTS_HOME_PATH)/resources/Makefile.include

# No pre or post build rules are necessary, override the default set on Makefile.include
pre-build: ;
post-build: main-build ;
@echo $(CC)
@echo $(OSTYPE)

 # ---------------------------------------------------
```

Additionaly, I've installed Webots on my Windows box and copied the installation folder to the installation folder on my Linux box, so that I could have access to the pre-compiled Windows libraries.

The problem is when the linker tries to find a couple of libraries (`-lController` and `-lCppController`, which are appended inside `Makefile.include`):

```
# linking build/release/darwin_socket.exe
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -s -Wl,--enable-auto-import -o build/release/darwin_socket.exe build/release/main.o build/release/DarwinRobot.o build/release/dyn_system.o build/release/writefilestuff.o build/release/socket_boost.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lws2_32 -lpthread -lboost_system-mt -lboost_serialization-mt -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/resources/projects/robots/darwin-op/libraries/darwin/darwin.dll ../../lib/OPKinematics/lib/libOPKinematics64.a  -lmingw32 -B"/usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0" -L"/usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib" -lController -lCppController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/libController.a when searching for -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/Controller.lib when searching for -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/Controller.dll when searching for -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/libController.a when searching for -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/libController.a when searching for -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/Controller.lib when searching for -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/Controller.dll when searching for -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/Controller.lib when searching for -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32 /bin/ld: cannot find -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/libCppController.a when searching for -lCppController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/CppController.dll when searching for -lCppController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/libCppController.a when searching for -lCppController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/libCppController.a when searching for -lCppController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/lib/CppController.dll when searching for -lCppController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lCppController
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/webots/resources/windows_home/resources/Makefile.include:529: recipe for target 'build/release/darwin_socket.exe' failed
make: *** [build/release/darwin_socket.exe] Error 1
```

From what I've gathered, this issue is usually caused when trying to link 32-bit libraries to a 64-bit binary (or vice-versa), but I have no `-m32` or `-m64` flags on my makefile or on `Makefile.include`. My OSs are both 64-bit, so I assume there should not be any problem with the type of libraries.

I've tried using Webots' native linux installation folder instead, but I encounter similar issues:

```
# linking build/release/darwin_socket.exe
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -s -Wl,--enable-auto-import -o build/release/darwin_socket.exe build/release/main.o build/release/DarwinRobot.o build/release/dyn_system.o build/release/writefilestuff.o build/release/socket_boost.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lws2_32 -lpthread -lboost_system-mt -lboost_serialization-mt -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic /usr/share/webots/resources/projects/robots/darwin-op/libraries/darwin/darwin.dll ../../lib/OPKinematics/lib/libOPKinematics64.a  -lmingw32 -B"/usr/share/webots\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0" -L"/usr/share/webots/lib" -lController -lCppController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lController
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lCppController
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/webots/resources/Makefile.include:529: recipe for target 'build/release/darwin_socket.exe' failed
make: *** [build/release/darwin_socket.exe] Error 1
```

which is rather strange, because both `libController.so` and `libCppController.so` are present inside `/usr/share/webots/lib/`.

So what exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm working with Webots since years but never tried that. Not sure at all, but wouldn't it because you should use the libController.dll file (windows one) rather than libController.so (linux one).